# Warning in IOS when keyboard appear connect with device ( not for Simulator)

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, ios8.1

I have just put `textfield` in my controller class and select `keyboard` type to number pad from interface builder.
  I have seen this warning in console when keyboard appears.

```
Can't find keyplane that supports type 5 for keyboard iPhone-Portrait-PhonePad; using 2870935746_Portrait_iPhone-Complex-Pad_Default
```

Comment: I have run this on device not in simulator. I know in simulator how to fix it.But on device we don't have such options.

Comment: This question should be reopened since the OP is asking about hardware support not sofware - the simulator. We know how to fix the problem for the simulator but we dont know how to get rid of this error that can occur on the iPhone device.